# Sails.getDatastores is not a function

Tags: sails.js

I'm having an issue, when I want to perform a MongoDB database operation every time I boot SailsJs (v1.0.0-49), declaring db like this:

```
const db = sails.getDatastore().manager
```

But I get the following:

> TypeError: sails.getDatastore is not a function

**UPDATE:** I am not using sails (Waterline) Models.

Now, I've tried using it in config/bootstrap.js, as a Hook and as a Service, with no success. I've also asked in a related issue in their repository without any response since last year.

Here's the link of my original post:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4156

Comment: Since it does not say that cannot call method of undefined, it means sails object does exist. Have You tried to console.log(sails) to check which methods are accessible?

Comment: Also if it's showing that issue on startup, could it be that DB drivers, providers, services not initialized yet?

Comment: Also, `.getDatastore()` and it's manager can be accessed via model. Check official documentation: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/manager

Comment: It is working fine when used in controllers, it shows up only when I try to run it in a Hook/bootstrap, but the issue is that I cannot use it as a Model, because I'm not using Waterline Models

Comment: getDatastore comes with Waterline. At least You've to load it. Search for `npm sails-hook-orm`. But there is another way, just use natively mongodb (mysql) module and do connection directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `getDatastore().manager` on a **model** not the sails object.
if you have some model named `MyModel` then you access the datastore manager like this :

```
const db = MyModel.getDatastore().manager;
```

check the [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/manager).

Comment: I am not using Waterline, thus there's no model to call it on. In globals.js: {models: false,}

Comment: @galgo: Did you figure it out?

Comment: We created "empty" models in the model file so I could call on them. @AbhishekSoni

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are allowed to call getDatastore() directly on the Sails object OR against the model. But this is a Waterline feature wired into Sails:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/sails-get-datastore